# Centering a figure with multiple subfigures

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, graphs

I'm trying to center graphs in a 2x3 grid. As can be seen from the image output the code places the graph slightly to the right of the page. Ideally I want the vertical gap between graphs to be in the center of the page. I think there is something obvious wrong with my code but i'm not sure what! Any thoughts?

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=2\textwidth]{/Bond/Brazil}
        \caption{Figure 1.1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \qquad
    \qquad
    \qquad
    \qquad
    \qquad
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=2\textwidth]{/Bond/Brazil}
        \caption{Figure 1.2}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=2\textwidth]{/Bond/Chile}
        \caption{Figure 1.3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \qquad
    \qquad
    \qquad
    \qquad
    \qquad
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=2\textwidth]{/Bond/China}
        \caption{Figure 1.4}
    \end{subfigure}

     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=2\textwidth]{/Bond/Colombia}
        \caption{Figure 1.5}
    \end{subfigure}
    \qquad
    \qquad
    \qquad
    \qquad
    \qquad
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=2\textwidth]{/Bond/Czech_Republic}
        \caption{Figure 1.6}
    \end{subfigure}
```

Comment: Replace `[width=2\textwidth]`by `[width=\textwidth]` and your images will not flow into the right margin any more. However, there will be a quite huge white space in the middle. So you might also want to remove the `\qquad`s and use a more suitable width for your subfigures.

Comment: I'd like to point out that @leandriis' answer is the most straightforward for fixing the immediate problem (although Zarko provided a very thorough analysis). This is just what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- similar questions was already asked many, many times ...
- your code snippet is not complete
- newer provide only code snippet, but complete small document called *minimal working example (mwe)*, which begin with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`, has in preamble loaded only to your problem relevant packages and exhibits your problem.

  - show result of your mwe in question, not in link (after time this link can become dead)

your code is rather strange (see [leandriis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134144/leandriis) comment above). after removing all superfluous code and arrange your image as you show on image in link, i obtain:

[image]

where red lines show page layout and your images are replaced by example images from `graphicx` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Figure 1.1}
    \end{subfigure}%
\hfill%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-B}
        \caption{Figure 1.2}
    \end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Figure 1.3}
    \end{subfigure}%
\hfill%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-B}
        \caption{Figure 1.4}
    \end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Figure 1.5}
    \end{subfigure}%
\hfill%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-B}
        \caption{Figure 1.6}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure 1 \dots}
\label{fig:fig 1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

in your document replace `example-image-...` with actual ones and remove all stuff of `showframe`.

Comment: Thansk so much, appreciate the help. Works perfectly.

Comment: @BradleyJordan, you are welcome! you also can accept answer by clicking on the check mark on the top left side of answer :-)

Comment: Done, in future i'll ask questions properly now that I understand how the forum works. Newbie to this, but seems a great community!

Comment: @Zarko Why % is needed after `\hfill` ?

Comment: @adosar, it disable empty space after `\hfill`. If distance between images is sufficient large, than this is not (so)  important, but when is close to empty space between word,  this space can disturb `subfigure` distribution in the figure.